# Get Info from CollectionView Cell Within TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a collectionView within a tableview and I am trying to access the collection view's indexPath in order to get its contents upon selecting it.

Here is my code:

```
   TableView

     //This grabs the indexPath of the collectionView Selected with its contents
     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt      indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selectedDeal = dealArray[indexPath.row]
    }

   ViewController

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) 
     {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SpecialPicTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! SpecialPicTableViewCell
      //Defines the selected
      let deal = cell.selectedDeal

      //Grabs selected information here
      dealSelected = deal.title ?? ""

      //Then segues
      performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToDeal", sender: nil)
      tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
     }
```

However, the selection does not register with the TableView. Nothing happens as a result.

Answer (score 0):

The only information in the collection view is information you put there. You shouldn't need to get any information out of the collection view cell because you already have it.

The code you posted dequeues (possibly creates) a cell, cleans it up and gets it ready for use (possibly reuse.) That cell that you essentially created will know nothing about the data that is in the cell that was selected.

What you should be doing instead, is referring to the array where you store the deals to display and figuring out what deal is at the selected index path.